# Deploy multiple projects to Azure using Github Actions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I'm encountering the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184613/deploying-multi-project-asp-net-core-web-app-to-azure-app-service-using-github-a). I have already modified the auto-generated yml file such that I have this in the build steps:

**Before:**

```
- name: Build with dotnet
    run: dotnet build --configuration Release

  - name: dotnet publish
    run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

**After:**

```
  - name: Build with dotnet
    run: dotnet build {project folder}/project_name.csproj --configuration Release

  - name: dotnet publish
    run: dotnet publish {project folder}/project_name.csproj -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

The deployment is successful where both the build and deploy actions are completed without any errors. However, my web app is not loading showing a 403 error, and when I checked the wwwroot folder it's empty and no files were deployed.

Here's the relevant code for the deployment:

```
deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'dev'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'myappname'
          slot-name: 'dev'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_****** }}
          package: .
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Could you please share your GitHub Repo?

Comment: I can't, it's a private repo

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet publish` doesn't publish your app to Azure App Service. It will prepare just a package for deployment.

To deploy app to Azure App Service you need to use this task `azure/webapps-deploy`.

Take a look here on [an example workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-azure/deploying-net-to-azure-app-service#creating-the-workflow):

```
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

# GitHub recommends pinning actions to a commit SHA.
# To get a newer version, you will need to update the SHA.
# You can also reference a tag or branch, but the action may change without warning.

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to an Azure Web App

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: MY_WEBAPP_NAME   # set this to your application's name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '5'                 # set this to the .NET Core version to use

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Set up dependency caching for faster builds
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

If you want to deploy multiple project you can do it using matrix like here

```yaml
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - app: 'web-app-name-1'
            artifact: 'artifact-path-1'
            profileName: 'profile-1'
          - app: 'web-app-name-2'
            artifact: 'artifact-path-2'
            profileName: 'profile-2'
          - app: 'web-app-name-3'
            artifact: 'artifact-path-3'
            profileName: 'profile-3'
    
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: ${{ matrix.artifact }}

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ matrix.app }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets[matrix.profileName] }}
        package: ${{ matrix.artifact }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and you are correct about the deployment and I should have added it in post. I just did, can you take a look and see what's missing? Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure that use use correct directory here `package: .` Please add a step to list directories before deploying app.  Could you also attach logs from `azure/webapps-deploy` step?

Comment: I'm sure the directory is correct. Anyway, I tried the deployment from Visual Studio and inspected the yml files. I assume that VS will write the correct path. Anyway, I checked and the WORKING_DIRECTORY is set to my target project folder. The AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH is set to the project directory with the "published" path (i.e. MY_PROJECT\published). I deployed to a new slot to make a fresh test deployment. Build and deployment was successful but my "site>repository" and "site>wwwroot" are both empty.